# How to display lines x-3 and x-1 based on contents of line x?

Tags: sed

I have a file which contains the following content. i want to extract the two  fields out of it i.e 1st field (2019-04-09T05:25:26) before the word "Running" and 3rd field (run_stat) before "Running"

### demo.log

```
"$id": "9",
"TaskExecId": 7917159,
"WorkflowExecId": 2560888,
"TaskId": 215537,
"TaskName": "run_stat", ------   3rd field
"TaskTypeId": "Custom",
"StartDate": "2019-04-23T05:25:26", -- 1st field
"ExecStatusId": "Running",
"HasStep": 0.0,
"HasTaskExecLog": 0.0,
"HasTaskExecReport": 0.0
```

i have written the below script but it is not working .

```
#!/bin/bash
a=$( date "+%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S" )
b=`sed -n -e '/Running/{x;$!N;p;D;}' -e h demo.log| sed -e 's/ //g;N;s/\n/~/g;s/"//g;s/ //g;s/,//g;s/[a-z]//g;s/[A-Z]//g;s/_//g;s/://g;s/~0.0//g'`
c=$((a-b))
echo $a
echo $b
echo $c
```

Expected out should display below :

```
run_stat
<current datetime> - 2019-04-23 05:25:26
```

Comment: Hi All, is there any way i can achieve the result?

Comment: tried but not giving any ouput.

Comment: Is that the entirety of the log, or is it a JSON file?

Comment: its a log file which will have different statuses like running,complete,failed etc and i want to extract those fields based on the status "Running"

Comment: I've edited your question to "limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer. **Avoid asking multiple distinct questions at once**."

Comment: Whether date is part of your log file or do you add it before extracting the required details?

Comment: @acs005 yes date is a part of log file and i need to calculate the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More involved but less brain-bending, maybe -

```
#! /bin/bash

bare() { 
  x="$1"
  x=${x%?,*}   # assuming the exact format shown, 
  x=${x##*: ?} # these strip the quotes and everything outside them
  echo "$x"
}

declare -i ndx=0
declare -a log
while read line
do [[ "$line" =~ Running ]] && break
   log[ndx++]="$line"
done < demo.log

bare "${log[ndx-3]}" # run_stat

y=$( bare "${log[ndx-1]}" )
start=$( date -d "$y" +%s )
now=$( date +%s )
echo $(( now - start ))
```

The difference spits out in seconds.

Hopefully you could extrapolate that to your circumstance.

Comment: For the record, this isn't an ideal format for parsing this way... Maybe `jq`?

Comment: Very much agreed; that's why I tried asking them if it was JSON but didn't get an answer.

Comment: Thanks all for providing me the solutions for my problem . Actually it looks similar to JSON but its a text file and i need to parse this way only.. Paul's Solution worked for me and for calculating the date i  did in this way :                                                              start=`sed -n -e '/Running/{x;$!N;p;D;}' -e h demo.log | sed -e 's/ //g;N;s/\n/~/g;s/"//g;s/ //g;s/,//g;s/[a-z]//g;s/[A-Z]//g;s/_//g;s/://g;s/-//g;s/~0.0//g'`
now=$( date "+%Y%m%d%H%M%S" )
#now=$( date +%s )
#echo $start
#echo $now
echo $(( now - start ))

Answer (score 0):

Awk is probably a better tool for this. You can keep a history of the previous 3 lines and then work with them when needed:

```
gawk -v "d=$(gdate "+%Y-%m-%d %H%M%S")" '
    /^"ExecStatusId": "Running"/ {
        match(l3, /"TaskName": "(.*)",/, a)
        print a[1]

        match(l1, /"StartDate": "(.*)",/, a)
        print d"-"a[1]
    }
    {l3=l2; l2=l1; l1=$0;}
' demo.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Tested in GNU AWK & Sed:

```
grep -B3 'Running' file.txt | awk '/TaskName/ {print $2} /StartDate/ {print "current datetime - " $2}' | sed -e 's/[",]//g'
```

Output:

```
run_stat
current datetime - 2019-04-23T05:25:26
```

Comment: I think he actually wanted the "current datetime - ..." part calculated, but the `-B3` is a great, simple way to grab just the relevant lines...

Comment: @PaulHodges Oh, My bad! I should have looked at his code. I just read the issue and input, and provided the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you have name-value pairs its best to first populate an array of that mapping (`f[]` below) and then you can just access the values by their names:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {FS="^[[:space:]]*\"|\"[[:space:]]*:[[:space:]]+\"?|\"?,?[[:space:]]*$"; OFS=" - "}
$1 == "$id" { prt() }
{ f[$2] = $3 }
END { prt() }

function prt() {
    if ( f["ExecStatusId"] == "Running" ) {
        sub(/T/," ",f["StartDate"])
        print f["TaskName"]
        print now, f["StartDate"]
    }
    delete f
}

$ awk -v now="$(date +'%Y-%m-%d %T')" -f tst.awk file
run_stat
2019-04-24 19:59:38 - 2019-04-23 05:25:26
```

Answer (score 0):

tried on gnu sed

```
sed -Ez 's/.*\n(([^\n]+\n){3})"\S+":\s*"Running".*/\1/;h;s/[^:]+:\s*"(\S+)".*/\1\n/p;g;s/.*\n[^:]+:\s*"(\S+)".*/\1/' demo.log
```